# Empty sqlite database in QT

Tags: database, sqlite, qt

I am having an issue accessing my sqlite database in QT.  I have stored my database in my project folder and done the following:

```
.pro file

RESOURCES += \

sqfiles.SOURCES = db.sqlite
sqfiles.path = .

DEPLOYMENT += sqfiles
```

I can open my database and is states it is valid but has no tables, thus I cannot do any search commands and get the following error after I run this code:

```
QSqlQuery query("SELECT * FROM shifts", db);
if(!query.exec())
{
    qDebug() << query.lastError().text();
    qDebug() << "ERROR" << endl;
    return;
}
while(query.next())
{
    QString name = query.value(1).toString();
    qDebug() << name << endl;
}
```

> message: "No query Unable to fetch row"

When I open this db outside of my QT project I have multiple tables and can run queries.

Any suggestions or idea on what is going wrong?  Why does it think my database is empty?

Comment: And rename your sqlite file with extension `.db`.

Answer (score 2):

This is my query to create table (using SQLITE Database browser program).

```
CREATE TABLE shifts (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, NUMBER NUMERIC, TEXT TEXT);
INSERT INTO shifts VALUES(1,123,'ABC');
INSERT INTO shifts VALUES(2,456,'DEF');
```

And this is my Qt code.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QSqlRecord>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName("database.db");
    db.open();
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.exec("SELECT * from shifts");
    while (query.next())
    {
        qDebug() << "NUMBER" << query.value(0).toString()
                    << "TEXT" << query.value(1).toString();
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

Output

```
NUMBER "1" TEXT "123" 
NUMBER "2" TEXT "456"
```

I did not add SQLite info in project file. Rather I used `QSqlDatabase` and added `QT += sql`. Oh yes, make sure you have SQLITE driver. Test like this.

```
qDebug() << QSqlDatabase::drivers();
```

Here is my output.

```
("QSQLITE", "QMYSQL3", "QMYSQL")
```

Todo

- Check if you have SQLite driver installed with Qt
- Check if the database file has correct name. Use absolute path rather than relative path.

Comment: #include <QStringList> for show  :  qDebug() << QSqlDatabase::drivers();